# How can I enter the second letter listed in the keyboard layout for a key?

Tags: unity, keyboard-layout, language-support

This is screenshot from an Ubuntu 16.04 keyboard layout chart

[image: ubuntu keyboard layout chart]

As you see there are two different letters: 'Ө' and 'Ф'

When I press this key, it prints 'Ө', but I need letter 'Ф'

How to get this letter?

Comment: Did you try Alt+key?

Comment: Yes! It doesn't work